# Adding custom text inside an automatically generated output from an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, rss

I have the following code:

```
$feed->item([
    'title' => $post->title,
    'guid' => $post->guid
]);
```

which generates the following output for me:

```
<title>Title of post</title>
<guid>Guid of the post</guid>
```

I want to include the following tag in it

```
<enclosure url="image.jpg" length="1" type="image/jpeg"/>
```

How this will be possible, considering that the code above, generated automatically an opening and closure tag for each attribute.

PS: The library im using is: https://github.com/thujohn/rss-l4

Comment: Take a look at the render() method. I think your answer is there. (Note the checking for | and ;

Comment: This is my rendering method - but im not sure what to change there in order to achieve my goal: https://pastebin.com/53B0sJPw

Comment: I’m no expert in xml; when I hear the term, I shudder and run away if possible. That being said, we need to be precise in defining terms. Up to this point, you haven’t touched an attribute yet; adding attributes is what you’re trying to solve. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php  The real issue, I think, is how do you represent that in the array $this->item so that render() will know how to parse it.

Comment: Here’s an idea, renaming things a bit so as to define things.  What you call parameters, I’d call tagNames. You pass tagNames as keys into $feed->item(). The values for each of these keys can be a string or an array. If a string, addChild(). If an array, addAttribute().

Comment: Well what Im trying to achieve is to include this enclosure url line. Im using this github repo: https://github.com/thujohn/rss-l4 and the owner of it, has already provided support for the command here: https://github.com/thujohn/rss-l4/pull/24 - Im just not sure how to add this part of code inside my initial described code of $feed->item array of attributes, since enclosure attribute seems to have child attributes.